# Is Next.js 13.4 cache and revalidate broken?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Fairly new to both Next and React. Please let me know if it's me or a bug?

### I have the following Next 13.4.2 app:
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pogyv2)

`/app/[id]/page.tsx`

```
export const revalidate = 0;
export const fetchCache = "force-no-store";
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=America/New_York`,
    { cache: "no-store", next: { revalidate: 0 } }
  );
  return res.json();
}

async function getRnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

export default async function Page({ params }: Props) {
  const data = await getData();
  let rnd = await getRnd();

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <h1> Page ID: {params.id}</h1>
      <p className="text-6xl">Random: {rnd}</p>
      <p>Time: {data.dateTime}</p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

From what I've read and understood [from the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) `revalidate = 0` or `force-no-store` or `{ cache: "no-store", next: { revalidate: 0 } }` should all "force" a server-side re-render of the page which should get a new random number and a new API request for the current time.

What I experience is stale data no matter what the cache setting is. I've noticed that if I let the tab with this app stay open for a few minutes and come back to it... the data will magically refresh.

This happens on both `codesandbox` and `localhost` on either `dev` or `build`.

Can you explain it to me like I only know PHP? :)

P.S: I did find [the following issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42290) but I'm not sure if that's on an older version and whether it was already fixed...

Comment: yeah, issue still open https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42991

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use both options

```
{ cache: "no-store", next: { revalidate: 0 } }
```

if you build your app with `next build`, you will see this on terminal

```
 only one should be specified
```

`next: { revalidate: 0 }` is static rendered content.

`cache: "no-store"` is server side content.

you have to choose one of them